# Call rest post method from jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to call my rest API from Jenkins after build of job was ended with build status. As example when build was fail I want to send what are the recent changes has done, who start the build etc. I think there might be a specific plugin for doing this but I could not found. My next plane is to customize Jenkins Hipchat plugin to sent massage to my API. But it may difficult. Can anyone suggest me a plugin or method for do this.

Comment: Can you just run a shell command which posts via curl?

Comment: Yes it is also possible. But problem is what are the parameter which can use to get build status, Job name, changes before last build, who start the build etc. (Like Jenkins hipchat plugin)

Answer (score 0):

The standard environment variables are listed here:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project

If you need additional parameters you have to query them yourself. I usually do it with groovy, and in you case I guess it would be lastBuild()

Here is an example to check if job has run on master or not:

```
import hudson.model.*

jenkins = Hudson.instance

items = jenkins.items
Collections.shuffle(items)


for (item in items){
  def job = item.getLastBuild()
  if(job != null){
        if(job.getBuiltOnStr() == null || job.getBuiltOnStr() == "")
          println "Built in master: " + job.toString()
  }
}
```

Please check api documentation to determine what information you need: http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/AbstractBuild.html
I guess the user is is a build-cause: http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Run.html#getCauses()
But you have to dig around yourself to get the information you need. If this is too much job, and you have everything you need in the hipchat plugin, that might be simpler for you.